# How does regedit.exe create empty binary values

Tags: winapi, registry

I opened up regedit and made an empty binary value monitoring it using ProcessMonitor.exe. I set up a filter so that it included anything mentioning the registry path of the empty binary value's key and excluded everything else. When making a new binary value, it creates the unnamed one, then when I rename it to something else it deletes the unnamed one. However, it doesn't set anything with the new name, it just queries the value which returns an error until after I close the key in regedit then open it again and it now queries successfully the empty REG_BINARY.

At no point do I see any set value calls, and I looked on msdn, it doesn't say querying non-existing values creates them. How does it make the new value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this on XP, you can also get the RegMon output, and that lists SetValue:

ProcMon:

```
"Sequence","Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail","Event Class"
"8456","20:15:47,6493609","regedit.exe","420","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry"
"8559","20:15:51,2066619","regedit.exe","420","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\test\foo","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry"
"8560","20:15:51,2066761","regedit.exe","420","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1","SUCCESS","Type: REG_BINARY, Length: 0","Registry"
"8561","20:15:51,2066864","regedit.exe","420","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1","SUCCESS","Type: REG_BINARY, Length: 0","Registry"
"8562","20:15:51,2075572","regedit.exe","420","RegDeleteValue","HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1","SUCCESS","","Registry"
"8618","20:15:52,9198131","regedit.exe","420","RegCloseKey","HKCU\Software\test","SUCCESS","","Registry"
```

RegMon:

```
1   2.38380957  regedit.exe:420 QueryValue  HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1 NOT FOUND       
2   2.38436174  regedit.exe:420 SetValue    HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1 SUCCESS     
3   5.36779499  regedit.exe:420 QueryValue  HKCU\Software\test\foo  NOT FOUND       
4   5.36780643  regedit.exe:420 QueryValue  HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1 SUCCESS     
5   5.36781597  regedit.exe:420 QueryValue  HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1 SUCCESS     
6   5.36884880  regedit.exe:420 SetValue    HKCU\Software\test\foo  SUCCESS     
7   5.36890793  regedit.exe:420 DeleteValueKey  HKCU\Software\test\New Value #1 SUCCESS     
8   9.04430676  regedit.exe:420 CloseKey    HKCU\Software\test  SUCCESS
```

The regmon output looks like a rename operation to me (QV,QVx2,SV,DV) Maybe regmon uses hooking and procmon uses the documented registry monitor api (Or maybe a procmon bug?)

I tested both the latest and a older version on procmon; v1.37 (The older versions don't have a huge ETW delay when you toggle monitoring on/off on XP)

Comment: I wrote a python program that parses exported CSV results from ProcMon to registry import files, so you set up your system how you like it (including usage of tweak utilities, etc), and it filters out the crap and produces a merge file. Now it looks like I should have chosen the RegMon program instead as my weapon of choice :) That's clearly a ProcMon bug it can't see the change. It means I'm going to re-write my parser, or maybe I can't be bothered it's close enough, I'll put it on glitorious or some such and let someone else do the dirty work :)

Comment: To be fair, it's probably the official events monitoring system at fault not procmon, but it still counts as a procmon bug since they chose the wrong monitoring system.